# How to make lines symmetrical in PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have been working on these lines, and I want to create it like in picture, but I got complicated. How do I get line symmetrical like in picture below?

This is what I tried so far, not much :/

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

for y in range (-4000, 2000, 200):
    draw.line(((y, img.size[0]+img.size[0]), 
               (img.size[1]+img.size[1]+img.size[1], y)), (0, 0, 0), 20)

for x in range (-2000, 1000, 100):
    draw.line(((x,-x),(x+img.size[0], -x+img.size[1]+img.size[1])), (0, 0, 0), 20)
```

I want to create lines like this...

[image: sample image]

Comment: and what did you get with your program? Maybe first use `print()` to see what values you calculated.

Comment: maybe better use different names for variables - in both loop you could use `for x`, and mayb use `w = img.size[0]`, `h = img.size[1]`. Symetrical line should have similar calculations but with different sign but your calculations are very different in both `for`-loops. And they should be much simpler - like `(x, 0), (x+offset, h)`.

Comment: I don't understand why in one `for` you use step 200 and in other step 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you created too complicated calculations and this made problem

Symmetrical lines should have similar calculations but with different sign.

Both should have `y` from `0` to `height`

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

w = img.size[0]
h = img.size[1]

offset = 400
step = 100

for x in range(-offset, w+offset, step):
    draw.line(((x, 0), (x+offset, h)), (0, 0, 0), 20)
    draw.line(((x, 0), (x-offset, h)), (0, 0, 0), 20)
    
img.show()
```

Gives

[image]

And for `offset = image_width` (`offset = 1000`) it gives rectangles

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Version which use `move_x`, `move_y` to move lines.

Because after moving lines it shows end of lines so I use `line_width` to start and end line outside window.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000), (0, 200, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

w = img.size[0]
h = img.size[1]

line_width = 10 # 

move_x = 10
move_y = 50

offset = w # 400
step = 200

for x in range(-offset, w+offset, step):
    x1 = x  + move_x - move_y - line_width
    x2 = x1 + offset          + line_width*2
    
    x3 = x  + move_x + move_y + line_width
    x4 = x3 - offset          - line_width*2
    
    draw.line(((x1, 0-line_width), (x2, h+line_width)), (0, 0, 0), line_width)
    draw.line(((x3, 0-line_width), (x4, h+line_width)), (0, 0, 0), line_width)

img.show()
img.save('output.png')
```

[image]

Comment: This is cool, thanks!

Comment: I have one small question, what i need to do that lines not start from corners?

Comment: to move left or right you have to change `range()` for `x`  - ie `move = 10` and `range(-offset+move, w+offset, step):` will move all line 10 pixels right. To move up or down you have to change `y` in `drawLine` - ie. `move = 10` and `draw.line(((x, 0-move), (x+offset, h))` will move all lines 10 pixels up

Comment: I added new version with `move_x`, `move_y`

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!